# Virasoro Algebra as Central Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Schottenloher introduces the Lie-bracket of the central extension as a linear combination $$[x,y]=[x,y]_0 + \Theta(x,y)$$ where $[\cdot,\cdot]_0$ is the Lie-bracket of the original Witt-algebra and $\Theta \in Z^2(W,\mathbb{C})$.

After some algebra he finds
$$\Theta(L_m,L_n)= \frac{m-n}{m+n} \Theta(L_0,L_{m+n}) \, .$$
Now he argues that you can always add a homomorphism $\mu \in {\rm HOM}_{\mathbb{C}}(W,\mathbb{C})$ to $\Theta$, defined by
$$\mu(L_n)=\frac{\Theta(L_0,L_n)}{n} \\
\mu(L_0) = -\frac{\Theta(L_1,L_{-1})}{2} \, ,$$
and $\Theta'(x,y)=\Theta(x,y) + \mu([x,y])$. The essence is that $\Theta'=0$ is always $0$, except for $m+n=0$.

My question is, why is that always possible? One necessary condition obviously is, that $\mu$ satisfies the Jacobi identity i.e.
$$\mu\left([L_k,[L_m,L_n]]\right) + \mu\left([L_m,[L_n,L_k]]\right) + \mu\left([L_n,[L_k,L_m]]\right) \\
=(m-n)\mu\left([L_k,L_{m+n}]\right) + (n-k)\mu\left([L_m,L_{n+k}]\right) + (k-m) \mu\left([L_n,L_{k+m}]\right) \\
=\left\{ (m-n)(k-m-n) + (n-k)(m-n-k) + (k-m)(n-k-m) \right\} \mu\left( L_{k+m+n} \right) 
=0 \, .$$
Is that also sufficient? Is it always true that $\mu(x+y)=\mu(x)+\mu(y)$? How does this relate to the statement of the homomorphism? Is it just that
$$\mu\left([L_k,[L_m,L_n]]\right) + \mu\left([L_m,[L_n,L_k]]\right) + \mu\left([L_n,[L_k,L_m]]\right) \\
\mu\left([L_k,[L_m,L_n]] + [L_m,[L_n,L_k]] + [L_n,[L_k,L_m]]\right) = \mu(0)=0 $$
or is there more to it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't remember if it's covered, but Michael Penn just uploaded a video on the Virasoro algebra. https://youtu.be/u-umYsfju4w

Comment: Looks like that's what he hastily avoids^^
Anyway. I'm just wondering if this situation is kinda like a gauge-freedom you can use to impose a condition on the solution (remotely similarly to how maxwells equation allow the potentials to be modified by a gradient of a scalar function).